# Compiling Coffeescript from WebStorm on Windows

Tags: windows, coffeescript, webstorm

I know there are other questions and answers that are somewhat related to this, but I have not found anything specific to my problem.

Platform: Windows/nodejs/coffeescript/WebStorm

I have been able to set up Coffeescript compilation by calling coffee.cmd with appropriate parameters via External Tools. However, not all output ends up showing in the Run window. For instance, if there are parsing errors and compilation fails, it does so silently.

I would prefer to be able to hit a hotkey in WebStorm and compile my CoffeeScript instead of keeping a console window open to do so.

Is there any way I can forward syntax errors to the Run window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is an issue with WebStorm and StdErr, and has been submitted as a bug. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90129

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm has an inline lint for coffescript. So you can see errors underlined in code window.

CoffeeScript compiler setup for WebStorm
http://zsitro.com/coffeescript-compiler-setup-for-webstorm/